# Batch File: Activate conda environment then run a command and leave window open

Tags: windows, batch-file, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, conda

I am trying to achieve the following three commands in a batch file

```
cd D:\WorkingFolder
activate py3
jupyter notebook
```

Now, I can open a command window and type the 3 commands in sequence and everything works just fine. But I would like to create a batch file that can get me the same result. However, simply putting these commands in the batch file does not work, and I imagine it has something to do with the activate command going into a different environment. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "Does not work"? Does the Jupyter Notebook not open? Are there any error messages?

Comment: No errors, it just simply closes the command window after executing "activate py3"

Comment: I think what's happening is that the activate command opens a "new" batch shell, so anything after that is "stuck" in the previous shell...
I'm trying to do the same thing and looking for answers.